# how to fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token

I run a Js Calendar script, but my calendar don't show. 
I also getting this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ?
My code: 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {

            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
            });
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

            edit(event);

        },
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

            edit(event);

        },
        events: [
        <?php foreach($events as $event): 

            $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
            $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
            }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
        ?>
            {
                id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
            },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]
    });



});
```

Sombody how to fix it? 
I also downloadaed today a mobile checker composer, but i think is not influence it.
Interestingly, the code has worked so far, until today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unexpected token <" when using <?php in a Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896545/unexpected-token-when-using-php-in-a-javascript-file)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please only use relevant tags, I don't see how java is relevant here.

Comment: if I delete this part, the calendar already showing but I need events on it, so I think the problem will somewhere here: events: [

Comment: Ohh, sorry guys there was a database error, Some information there are blocked the event render, wasn't the script, Now I solved it! Thank you! :D